# Why do I get completely different results when subjecting my data to a t-test in different ways?

Tags: t-test, differences

I subjected my data to a t-test in two manners of which I expected the same output would be generated. It turned out it is not so. Now I would like to know wherein the profound differences in the data-analysis lie.

But first things first. My data consist of data A, B and their difference.

```
 DF<-data.frame(A = c(3.92,3.87,3.32,2.87),
                 B = c(3.36,3.19,2.53,2.49),
                 AminB = c(0.56,0.68,0.79,0.38))
```

I conducted t-tests in R in which I either compared A and B or I tested the difference of A-B to zero (which is what the one-sample t-test is doing).

Test 1: Code and result

```
t.test(DF$A, DF$B) 
t = 1.801, df = 5.9336, p-value = 0.1223
```

Test 2: Code and result

```
t.test(DF$AminB)
t = 6.8633, df = 3, p-value = 0.006333
```

Can someone explain what the difference of the inquiry is? I want to know if there is a difference in A and B. Why would a question such as A-B > 0 not work to ask for this? my reasoning is: If A and B are the same, then A-B = 0 and the p-value would be very high. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question by supplying your data using `dput()`?

Comment: you are doing a paired t test when calculating a-b, so i think you need to specify paired =TRUE in test 1 https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html

Comment: You don't say whether your data are actually paired. If they are, you shouldn't do a two-sample t-test (which is for independent samples), and if they aren't paired you shouldn't be subtracting elements pairwise as if they were paired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `t.test()` that you're doing a paired t-test.

```
d <- data.frame(
    A = c(3.92, 3.87, 3.32, 2.87), 
    B = c(3.36, 3.19, 2.53, 2.49), 
    `A-B` = c(0.56, 0.68, 0.79, 0.38), 
    row.names = c("R10a", "R2a", "R3a", "R7a")
)
t.test(d[, 1], d[, 2], paired = TRUE)
## > Paired t-test
## > 
## > data:  d[, 1] and d[, 2]
## > t = 6.8633, df = 3, p-value = 0.006333
## > alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
## > 95 percent confidence interval:
## >     0.3231282 0.8818718
## > sample estimates:
## >     mean of the differences 
## > 0.6025 

t.test(d[, 3])
##> One Sample t-test
##> 
##> data:  d[, 3]
##> t = 6.8633, df = 3, p-value = 0.006333
##> alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
##> 95 percent confidence interval:
##>     0.3231282 0.8818718
##> sample estimates:
##>     mean of x 
##> 0.6025
```

Now you get equal results as expected.